# How do you save your progress in offline mode?

Tags: operation-flashpoint-red-river

I'm playing *Operation Flash Point: Red River* in offline mode but can't save any progress.

Is there any work around or do you have to play the game online only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to connect to Games for Windows Live, you can create a local GFWL profile for game saves. You will not be able to access online leaderboards or use that save in online multiplayer.

The option to create a local GFWL profile is in one of the initial overlay pop-ups. You will need to scroll down to see the link among a paragraph of text.

[image: Create local profile]

Comment: Image is no longer available